# mapping Xml File in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am trying to map xml file in magento 2 while working on new module declaration through this command

```
 bin/magento dev:urn-catalog:generate .idea/misc.xml
```

the directory is (through pwd command)

```
/opt/lampp/htdocs/magento
```

at first it shows me this error

```
cache_dir "/opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/var/cache/" is not writable
```

So I have launched this command

```
chmod -R -v 777 var/cache
```

It shows me now this

```
 There are no commands defined in the "dev:urn-catalog" namespace.
```

Answer (score 0):

i notice that you were missing the required argument `ide`

you can refer the [devdocs here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/reference/cli/magento.html#devurn-cataloggenerate) for this command

its supposed to be

```
bin/magento dev:urn-catalog:generate [--ide IDE] [--] <path>
```

In case of PHP Storm which is the only IDE supported as if now

```
bin/magento dev:urn-catalog:generate --ide phpstorm .idea/misc.xml
```